# Do I have an SSH password?

Tags: authentication, passwords, ssh

I have an Ubuntu server hosted on DigitalOcean, I have been using SSH keys since the very beginning. (You can chose for it to be setup before the server instance has even been created). So I have never logged in remotely with a password.

I just checked my logs, and as expected there are hundreds of login attempts. I know I can install something like fail2ban, but I was just wondering if there actually is a password for it? I have never set one up, so I just assumed it would only be possible to login with an SSH Key.

How can I check this? If there is one, is it possible to just disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I was just wondering if there actually is a password for it?

Yes. SSH uses your system users (that's the whole idea of it, to allow users to remotely access a systems account), so there is a password for it (stored in `/etc/shadow`)

> If there is one, is it possible to just disable it?

Yes. You can (and should, as you are not using your password as you don't even know it) set `PasswordAuthentication no` in your SSH config file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for global, `~/.ssh/config` for user specific config). Afterwards you need to restart SSH for it to take affect (`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`)

Comment: Thank you! That explains a lot. I did some further research and found that no users actually had a password set in the shadow file, as all had a * or !, but I have disabled PasswordAuthentication too as an added layer of protection.